# Pagination : First page displays all the result

Tags: grails, pagination, gsp

I want to display the results of a queries on several pages, so I use the tag pagination.
I have correct outputs (I want 5 result per page) in all the pages but the first one.
In the first page, all results are displayed.

Controller :

```
 def questions(){
    def questions = Question.list(params)

    [questions: questions, total: Question.count()?:0, tags: Tags.list(), params: params]
}
```

View

```
 <g:each in="${questions}" var="question">                                      
      <div class="row">
         ${question?.body }
     </div>
 </g:each>
 <div class=pagination>
  <g:paginate controller="Question" action="list" total="${total}" max="5" params="${params}"/>
</div>
```

Why do I have all results in the first page ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `params` has no `max` value.

setting `params.max = 10` and then invoking `questions()` would result in 10 items for the first page.

```
// will result in Question.list(max: 10)
def questions = Question.list(params)
```

But, make sure if same action is called again for subsequent pages then `params.max` has to be set to 5 or totally removed because `max` from `<g:paginate>` would take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following line at the beginning of your controller action:

```
params.max = params.max ?: 5
```

If no `max` parameter is given the default value will be 5.